# Transform Python dictionary from {'a': ['A', 'B'], 'b': ['B', 'C']} --> {'A': ['a'], 'B': ['a', 'b'], 'C': ['b']}

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm starting out with this dictionary:

```
lower_to_upper = {"a": ["A", "B"],
                  "b": ["B", "C"]}
```

Then, I put all the capital letters into one list and printing that list...

```
upper_list = [upper for lo_uppers in lower_to_upper.values() for upper in lo_uppers]
print(f"upper_list:     {upper_list}")
```

... as expected gives this:

```
upper_list:     ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C']
```

Next, I create two dictionaries based on the list of upper case letters. One that has zeros as values (`upper_to_count`) and another that has empty lists are its values (`upper_to_lower`):

```
upper_to_count = dict.fromkeys(upper_list, 0)
upper_to_lower = dict.fromkeys(upper_list, [])
```

Next, I want to make it so that `upper_to_count` contains the number of entries an upper case letter occurs in in the original dictionary. Along the same lines, I want to populate the - for now - empty lists in `upper_to_lower` with the lower-case strings that were they keys for the respective upper case letters.

```
for i, upper_list in enumerate(lower_to_upper.values()):
    lower = list(lower_to_upper.keys())[i]
    for upper in upper_list:
        upper_to_count[upper] += 1
        upper_to_lower[upper].append(lower)
```

The result for `upper_to_count` is as expected. But the result for `upper_to_lower` is not as (I) expected. These statements ...

```
print(f"upper_to_count: {upper_to_count}")
print(f"upper_to_lower: {upper_to_lower}")
```

... print:

```
upper_to_count: {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}
upper_to_lower: {'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'C': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']}
```

My expectation was this:

```
print(f"upper_to_lower_exp: {upper_to_lower_exp}")
upper_to_lower_exp: {'A': ['a'], 'B': ['a', 'b'], 'C': ['b']}
```

That is a dictionary looking like this:

```
upper_to_lower_exp = {'A': ['a'],
                      'B': ['a', 'b'],
                      'C': ['b']}
```

I don't understand why I get `upper_to_lower` and not `upper_to_lower_exp`. What it is that I don't know that produces the output in `upper_to_lower` rather than `upper_to_lower_exp`?

I apologise for the strangeness of the title of my question. Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When iterating in parallel over keys and values the best practice is to use [`.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
lower_to_upper = {"a": ["A", "B"],
                  "b": ["B", "C"]}

upper_to_lower_exp = {}
for key, values in lower_to_upper.items():
    
    # iterate over each value
    for value in values:
        
        # if no key has been created so far for the value create one
        if value not in upper_to_lower_exp:
            upper_to_lower_exp[value] = []
        
        # append the key to the list of the corresponding value
        upper_to_lower_exp[value].append(key)

# upper_to_count is just upper_to_lower_exp but with the length of the lists instead
upper_to_count = {k: len(vs) for k, vs in upper_to_lower_exp.items()}
print(upper_to_count)
print(upper_to_lower_exp)
```

**Output**

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 1}
{'A': ['a'], 'B': ['a', 'b'], 'C': ['b']}
```

Comment: The note on best practice re. `.items()` is appreciated. Even more so the suggested way of initializing the dictionary with `upper_to_lower_exp = {}`. The problem lies in the way fromkeys() initializes the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are initializing the `upper_to_lower` dictionary, but your code as-is works if initialized like this:

```
# `list(set(upper_list))` being ['A', 'B', 'C']
upper_to_lower = {k: [] for k in list(set(upper_list))}

for i, upper_list in enumerate(lower_to_upper.values()):
    lower = list(lower_to_upper.keys())[i]
    for upper in upper_list:
        upper_to_count[upper] += 1
        upper_to_lower[upper].append(lower)
```

Output:

```
{'B': ['a', 'b'], 'A': ['a'], 'C': ['b']}
```

Comment: I initialized `upper_to_lower` with classmethod .fromkeys(). Which is why my original code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In the official documentation the crucial tidbit is that the *value* in initializing a dictionary "refer to just a single instance" -- be that `None` or e.g. an empty list. Thus, when I append elements to this list all keys in the final dictionary will point to the same list.

> *classmethod* **fromkeys**(*iterable*[, *value*])
> Create a new dictionary with keys from iterable and values set to value.

> fromkeys() is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value defaults to None. All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead.
> ([enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=fromkeys#dict.fromkeys))

I had no idea. Many thanks to the answers provided!